# Symfony2 Doctrine

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I try to do a database query using

```
$position = $repository->findBy(
    array('id' => $profileId,'datum' => '10.07.2011'),
    array('timestamp', 'DESC')
);
```

the database looks like

```
id  haveInCircles   inOtherCircles  datum   timestamp
1   24  14  11.07.2011  1310403840
1   20  10  10.07.2011  1310317440
1   10  5   09.07.2011  1310317440
1   25  17  12.07.2011  1310468838
```

The result I get is always the data of the last day into the database. In this case '12.07.2011'.

Comment: What is the data type of that field (in your entity) and the column (in the database)

Comment: in database varchar(40) and in entity string

Comment: which is the primary key of your table?

Answer (score 4):

Using varchar for dates is probably the worst approach possible. Change the datum field to date or datetime, change your models accordingly so the doctine field is date and then do something like:

```
$position = $repository->findBy(
    array('id' => $profileId,'datum' => new Datetime('2011-07-10')),
    array('timestamp' => 'DESC')
);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Brief on schema practises which i would advice to review:
http://brixican.blogspot.ca/2011/04/5-mysql-best-practices-when-designing.html

Comment: It should actually be `array('timestamp' => 'DESC')`, see https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html?highlight=findby#by-simple-conditions

Answer (score 1):

If database field for 'datum' is datetime, try to use: 2011-07-10 format :-)

[Symfony2 articles](http://inchoo.net/author/darko.goles/?posts=1)

Comment: Its obvious that he didnt have the date as a datetime field, Doctrine would have flushed it with an other format.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that you should change the field to Datetime format, however if you are using Symfony2 in the developer mode you can check SQL logs (DB Queries) that correspond to your Doctrine ORM query builder and from there you may know what's wrong with your query builder